# SQL Join - Summing COUNT of Different Values

Tags: sql, join

Let's say I have two tables orgs and states
orgs is (o_ID, state_abbr) and states is (state_abbr, state)

```
o_ID     state_abbr
1        CT
2        OH
3        OH

state_abbr state
CT         Connecticut
OH         Ohio
Alabama    AL
```

I would like to create a view that shows the count of o_ID in each state:

```
state_abbr      state       count
CT              Connecticut 1
OH              Ohio        2
```

What kind of SQL Statement would I use?
The ones that I have tried only show the first state and sum all the counts.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select
    o.state_abbr,
    s.state,
    o.[count]
from states s
inner join
(
    select state_abbr, count(*) as count
    from orgs
    group by state_abbr
) o
on s.state_abbr = o.state_abbr
```

Comment: worked as soon as i removed the []'s; guess mySQL doesn't like square brackets. Thanks!!

Comment: @HPatel I'm sorry, I assumed you were using SQL Server (don't know why I thought that).  I've modified my post to reflect.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for a "GROUP BY" statement, where you tell the database how to group your data for counting.  You need to group by both "state_abbr" and "state", so your query would look like:

```
SELECT
    states.state_abbr
    , states.state
    , COUNT(*)
FROM
    orgs
    INNER JOIN states ON states.state_abbr=orgs.state_abbr
GROUP BY
    state_name
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT O.STATE_ABBR,S.[STATE],COUNT(S.[STATE]) FROM ORGS O INNER JOIN
STATES S ON O.STATE_ABBR = S.STATE_ABBR GROUP BY  O.STATE_ABBR,S.[STATE]