# SQL - selecting count of different value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, syntax

Assume I have table `count` and the column is (nilai, id_courses, id_lecturer)

```
nilai    id_courses    id_lecturer
-----    ----------    -----------
2        1             1
2        1             1
2        1             1
3        1             1
3        1             1
1        2             1
1        2             1
5        2             1
5        2             1
```

then I want to create view like this :

```
nilai    id_courses    id_lecturer   count
-----    ----------    -----------   -----
2        1             1             3
3        1             1             2
1        2             1             2
5        2             1             2
```

how to do that in SQL syntax?

I just know how to count 1 value with this code

`SELECT COUNT( nilai ) , id_courses, id_lecturer FROM count where nilai=1`

I've read this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9123349/sql-join-summing-count-of-different-values) but its to complex, so I don't know how it's work

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't tag products not involved.)

Comment: Tip of today: check out `GROUP BY`, and the aggregate function `COUNT()`.

Comment: @jarlh Im using MySQL on hostinger, thanks for the tip, and maybe that answer below is work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to count all distinct entries by grouping them. The query

```
SELECT nilai, id_courses, id_lecturer, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM count GROUP BY nilai, id_courses, id_lecturer
```

should exactly return the table you posted.